# How to skip local notification for a particular period?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I registered a local notification which will occur every day .But in my application we have a setting called out of office where the user can select his out of office period for a period .(example: From Nov 4 to Nov 10).In between these days i should not get the reminder.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just unregister notifications for that period. Fetch all the scheduled notifications using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications]` and cancel specific notification for the period defined.

Comment: Ya,actually i registered a single notification which repeats everyday except on weekends.Here i ll get only one notification to cancel and how do i skip the notification for a particular period when i register again ?

Comment: Its not necessary to have only one notification, you can create multiple notifications at different timestamp, so you can choose to create 2 notification one before and one after.

Comment: Yes we can, but as per app requirement when the user adds his out of period in his setting say(Dec 25 to Dec 31) now on(Nov 5), how can i skip my notification on those days ? As per apple for an application we can register only 64 notification and the remaining will be degraded.

Comment: Yes thats what I am saying don't need to create so many notifications. 1. You create a notification which repeats itself everyday. 2. Now if user sets Out period, you cancel 1. and create 2 notifications for period from today to start of out period, and then from end of out period onwards..